# How to use Django with Python 3 in an existing older venv?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, virtualenv

I Made lots of researches about it but it seems confusing to me because everyone say different things about it, and they didn't deal with virtual env particular case.

I'm on Mac OS X.
I was using Django 1.6 with Python 2.7.5 on a virtual env following [the Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django).

Now, I just want to update to Django 1.7 + Python 3.3.5.

The things I did:

- I installed Python 3.3.5 on MacOSX using official Python package (in system)
- I installed Django 1.7 using pip (in my virtual env only)

Now:

```
python --version
>>> Python 2.7.5
python3 --version
>>> Python 3.3.5
```

**What are the missing steps to perform sothat Django uses the Python 3.3.5 installed in my system?**

In my Django project, I have a `venv` folder. Typing `ls venv/bin` or `ls venv/lib` give me results with python2.7 results only. No trace of python3.

Other thing that shows Django is not "linked" to Python3:

```
foreman run python manage.py runserver
>>>Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)

foreman run python3 manage.py runserver
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a virtual env for Python 3.

   ```
   virtualenv -p /path/to/python3 /path/to/virtualenv
   ```
2. Activate python 3 virtualenv
3. Install django.

   ```
   pip install django
   ```

Comment: I just thought: I kept the Django 1.6 files (except the one in venv). Could it be a problem? for example, migrations directory is not created.

Comment: @DavidW., I don't have a clue about that. I hope you get answer from [your new question posted separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090634/django-1-7-migrate-cmd-has-a-random-behaviour-after-django-1-6-update).

Comment: Thanks falsetru! I created a separate Django 1.7 project + app to check files one by one. Nothing to note, files and architecture are identical (except the missing "migrations" directory).

Comment: FYI, migrations folder is automatically created when "activating" migrations with my app :) This is clean now.